# What is the difference between "clothes" and "clothing"?

Tags: differences, nouns

Do some google I find that *clothes* work like objects like:

> - You should pack your clothes.  → Yes
> - You should pack your clothing. → No

Can you tell me the main difference between *clothing* and *clothes*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Clothes** are those items you wear.

**Clothing** is pretty much the same, but it seems it can refer to a special type of clothes (the type it refers to depends on the context).

You can see a useful note on the [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/clothing) that I'll paste here for future reference:

> *Clothes or clothing?*
>
> **Clothing** is more formal than **clothes** and is used especially to mean `‘a particular type of clothes’`. There is no singular form of clothes or clothing: a piece/an item/an article of clothing is used to talk about one thing that you wear such as a dress or shirt.

Comment: Interestingly as well, one would not say "an article of clothes."

Answer (score 5):

There is really no difference. They are synonyms when used in that context.

The only real difference is that *clothing* may be used in a gerund phrase:

> Clothing the poor was Martin's principal objective.

Comment: But you use a verb form in your example, not a noun.

Answer (score 4):

If there is a difference, it is very slight. Both would be considered acceptable, but some might argue that "clothing" generally denotes a general category, whereas "clothes" indicates a specific set of clothing.