# A word for clothes, shoes, accessories?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

I'm looking for a word that applies to all the things a person can wear, e.g. clothes, shoes, accessories, etc. It musn't be too generic, e.g. *product*, *item*, etc.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “clothes” and “clothing”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25887/what-is-the-difference-between-clothes-and-clothing)

Comment: Related: It is often handy to have a single word for otherwise dissimilar items sharing an important property, e.g., "fluid" for anything that flows, whether liquid or gas.

Comment: How can something that is so general ("all the things a person can wear") not be necessarily generic?

Comment: 'Apparel' is still probably the best.

Comment: Agree that 'apparel' is the right term.

Answer (score 17):

These all fall under the category of *apparel*, *attire*, or simply *clothing*.

Comment: These all seem like good choices.

Comment: I would like to point out that *apparel* is different from *footwear* and *accessories*. Ever saw a discount banner saying **Flat 50% off on Apparel only!**??

Answer (score 7):

I used to own a clothing store which carried all of the items listed in your question:  The following descriptive terms, not already mentioned, are appropiate:

1. Threads
2. Wearables
3. Wears or Wear: mentioned above but can be prefixed by specific category: Mens, Womens, Kids, Sports, Night, Day, ie. Menswear or used more generally like:
4. Outerwear
5. Textiles
6. Garments

Also appropiate:

1. **Couture**

Although originally associated with custom or expensive fashion, it has become a more generalized term.

Origin:

> French in origin, from Old French *cousture* sewing, from Vulgar Latin *consutura*,
>   from Latin *consutus*, past participle of *consuere* to sew together, from
>   *com-* + *suere* to sew —
>   From: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/couture

Hope this helps!

Marcelous

Answer (score 4):

Clothing is quite adequate. For alternatives that are standard and fun, though maybe pretentious, consider:

- **Garb**. Has connotations of a particularly stylized sort of clothing, but may be used to describe any clothing from *"monkish garb"* to ["kids in combat garb"](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/garb). Similar to gear, but more general.
- [**Furnishings**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/furnishing). It includes any article of dress, be it clothing, footwear, haberdashery or accessories. I recall it most commonly used in context as ["men's furnishings"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/men%27s+furnishings) but not exclusively.
- **Accoutrement** or **accoutrements**. Plural is better. While seemingly French, it is accepted English language usage, [**see here**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accoutrement).
- **Trappings**. Refers to any sort of [**clothing and equipment combination**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trappings) whether a costume or military outfit. Includes clothes, footware, jewelry, insignia, sashes, scarves and hosiery.

Comment: Garb, Accoutrements, Trappings are all worthy of a vote.

Comment: @shinyspoongod Much obliged! You have no idea how long it took  to write that answer. It was really difficult for me to find (what I now know to be, but didn't then) hypernyms that were English words, or borrowed words, and standard usage, yet not considered `archaic`. Nor had I quite figured out SE markdown either. Newbie daze ~;o)

Comment: I wish I could vote for this twice. This is the only answer with intelligence in a storm of "Oh! Me too!"s.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard the term *rig*. It encompasses a person's whole look from head to toe. Sometimes a person's rig can determine their place on the social food chain.

Comment: Interesting. Is it a slang or in-group use? Can you point to any examples?

Answer (score 2):

I've heard people use the word *gear* as well, which means clothes and accessories.

> (Clothing & Fashion) Informal up-to-date clothes and accessories, esp those bought by young people.

[- As stated here.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gear)

Answer (score 2):

You could say ***wear***.  (Although not a common term for describing articles of attire in general, it's technically correct for what you want.)

Among many other definitions of the word, there's this one:

> **wear** (*noun*): clothing, especially of a particular kind or for a particular use. Often used in combination, e.g.: *rainwear*; *footwear*; *underwear*; *activewear*; *formalwear*; *eveningwear*.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the words *apparel*, *garment* or simply *dress*.

Answer (score 2):

Since we're all pitching in, I like **habiliments**. It can mean clothes in general, but also specialized clothing and gear.

http://www.wordnik.com/words/habiliment

Comment: Honorable mention in the context of my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

When referring to the combination of items someone is wearing, I'd go with [**outfit**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/outfit).

> a set of usually matching or harmonious garments and accessories worn together; coordinated costume; ensemble: a new spring outfit.

Answer (score 1):

Another word that has not been mentioned is *duds*.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can try to use garments or wardrobe or closet stuff

Comment: "Closet stuff"?

Comment: @Robusto You know: gremlins, grumpkins, and fabulous feather boas.