# What is a word that includes clothing, accessories, shoes, undergarments, outerwear, etc.?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A word for clothes, shoes, accessories?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35427/a-word-for-clothes-shoes-accessories)

As in all of those things as one, not outfit because I'm not necessarily taking about them put together. Like if you were looking through a store at all the different things you wouldn't say outfit. It's something like apparel but I looked up apparel and it just said clothing not including all the other stuff.