# "Guess dress brand" or "Guess clothes brand"?

Tags: brands

In case of process of guessing brand names while looking on logo.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about the clothing brand known as *Guess* or are you asking about the process of trying to determine a brand from a logo by guessing?

Comment: @bib I mean your second assumption not concrete brand name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you want to use this phrase/sentence?

Depending on the circumstances, you might want to use:

> Guess the brand of clothing
>
> Guess the clothing brand

Note that, in much the same way as in online forms we often see "Enter username" instead of "Enter your username", in some cases you can also skip the article:

> Guess clothing brand

Also, if e.g. you're constructing a survey in which you know everyone will know that you're talking about clothing, for simplicity's sake you might want to just go with:

> Guess the brand

Comment: Yeah. You have asked right question. I'm looking way to name android application. This application show logo and user should guess brand. Name should be short and clear as possible

Comment: **Guess clothing brand** seems best name (at least for me as non-native speaker). I've worried about using "clothing/clothes" but find answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25887/what-is-the-difference-between-clothes-and-clothing

Comment: @ruX Not that [Google fights](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22clothing+brand%22&word2=%22clothes+brand%22) are a very scientific way of checking anything, but "clothing brand" is significantly more popular than "clothes brand" (358K to 22K)....
I personally would also stick with "clothing" in this case.

Comment: I also check numbers of google search results :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. “Guess the brand of clothing represented by this logo,” or “Guess the clothing brand represented by this logo,” or (and not quite as correct sounding, although I think it is still correct) “Guess the clothes brand represented by this logo.” Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I mean first case: "Guess the brand of clothing represented by this logo", thanks

Answer (score 1):

Guess the brand of clothing...

Comment: Thank you for reply. It's possible to make short form, like "Guess clothing brand"?

Comment: No, it sounds broken as a sentence. "guess the clothing brand" is the closest but less elegant