# The grammar of 'clothes' versus 'clothing'

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammatical-number

Which of these is correct:

> - I didn't realize how much clothes you had on the floor
> - I didn't realize how much clothing you had on the floor

Any additional explanation about *clothes* versus *clothing* would be helpful.

This other question discusses the *meaning* of the two words, but doesn't help with the grammar problem above:[What is the difference between "clothes" and "clothing"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25887/what-is-the-difference-between-clothes-and-clothing)

Comment: _Clothing_ is a mass noun, like _shelving_ or _roofing_. _Clothes_ is already plural; it doesn't have a singular, and it doesn't have another plural. It's diverged too far in meaning from its original singular _cloth_. _I didn't realize how many clothes you had on the floor_ is correct.

Comment: Interesting. Where I'm from, it would be said like so: ""I didn't realize how **many** clothes you had on the floor"

Comment: @JohnLawler you answered the question, can you make this an actual answer please?

Comment: @GreyDog: To me, 'much' sounds better than 'many', but neither are much good. I'd prefer "I didn't realize _all the_ clothes...". Not exactly the same semantics. I just would not have gone down the path of 'many/much'

Comment: @davecw: This question has been marked as duplicate so I can't. This is one reason why I answer in comments so often. Plus, of course, it's a good discipline to say what you need to in 500 or so words.

Comment: This may be marked as a dup, but I'm sill confused on much vs many

Comment: @Mitch: True, it's all awkward. I believe that my comment is primarily based on geographic dialect.

Comment: @JohnLawler Now you can - and in however many words you'd like!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Clothes* is an example of a plural-only noun. There are a small minority of nouns in English which, when functioning as the heads of Noun Phrases, only occur in the plural. A few more examples are:

- police, people, scissors, trousers, arms, groceries.

Notice that not all of these are marked with the regular plural ending 's', for example: *police*. *Police* has no plural suffix at all - either in the writing or in the sound. As noted by Snailboat in a helpful comment below, those nouns that *are* marked for plurality can often occur without their plural '*s*' suffix as modifiers in other Phrases:

- a *trouser* press
- She's a proud upstanding *trouser*-wearing feminist

This phenomenon aside, these nouns normally only occur in the plural, they take plural verb forms, and importantly, only take quantifiers that are compatible with plural countable nouns. They don't permit quantifiers that are usually used with non-countable nouns. So for example they can often occur with *a few* and *many* and with numerals greater than 'one', but never with with *much*:

- many people, many trousers, many clothes
- few poeple, few trousers, few clothes
- five thousand police, ten trousers, two people,
- not much people*, not much trousers*, not much clothes*, (wrong)

*Clothes* is unusual because it has a non-countable cousin *clothing*:

- many clothing* (wrong)
- few clothing* (wrong)
- two clothing* (wrong)
- not much clothing

*Clothing* is used like other mass nouns. It is very useful for when we want to talk about just one garment, because we can use it with other nouns like *item* and *piece* in constructions such as:

- a piece of clothing
- one item of clothing

We can't do this with the noun *clothes*:

- one piece of clothes*
- two items of clothes*

So to answer the Original Poster's first concern, we have a choice between:

- I didn't realize *how much clothing* you had on the floor.
- I didn't realize *how many clothes* you had on the floor.

The latter sounds more natural - though it's still a bit clunky.

Comment: Although it's not relevant in the case of *clothes*, some of the words you list do have forms that are either singular or unmarked for number (depending on your analysis) which appear attributively: *scissor kick*, *trouser leg*, etc.  Unfortunately, all of my references on this subject are too brief: Quirk et al. 1985, p.1333, Huddleston & Pullum 2002 p.342, Biber et al. 1999 p.289 and 595.

Comment: @snailboat True! - but they can't function as the head of an NP, and as you say, it's difficult to determine whether they are singular or non-count. It's also true that some plural-only nouns such as *dishes*, *contents* or *supplies* have what look like singular versions. However, the meaning of these words is always slightly different - *a supply* never means *jam* for example. We cannot talk of *a content* in the introductory agenda of a book. It seems to me that the same is true of *a trouser leg*. The semantic content of *trouser* there isn't identical to the meaning of *trousers* - imo

Comment: @snailboat I've edited to include your well-made points. Does what I've written seem correct?

Comment: For what it's worth, my father, an English professor who regressed to the vernacular only with tongue in cheek, always spoke of ***a** scissors*.

Comment: Also for what it’s worth, _police_ occurs quite freely with either a singular or a plural noun, depending on whether you’re talking about individual police officers or the police as unified body. “The police lies under the jurisdiction of XYZ” would sound odd with a plural verb (at least to me), for example.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree that your example sounds (marginally+ to me but probably completely to other/most people) completely fine but - Hibernian aside - does '*the police is here*' sound ok to your *English* English ear?

Comment: @StoneyB I like *a scissors* on principle!

Comment: @Araucaria No, there I would expect a plural as well, because the focus is on the individuals that make up the police force, rather than on the monolith that is the police system.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Me too, I think. How does it contrast for you with *the government are/ the government is* ?

Comment: Same difference, except with the government, you’re less likely to be focusing on individuality and more likely to be focusing on monolithicality (such is the nature of governments). Also, _government_ can (just about) be used synecdochically to refer to a government building, whereas _police_ cannot really be used to mean ‘police station’, so that’s one kind of _government is_ that doesn’t have a _police_ equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

ACTIONS VS EXISTENCE

*Clothes* is  used when something is done to them,going to be done to them, or being done to them. *clothing* is used when describing the features of them.For example:

The wind picked up the clothes wile it was drying on the line.

That piece of clothing is rather dark

The piece of clothing was laying on the ground

In other words, *clothes* can belong to someone, in possession, and *clothing* is used  when talking about only the *clothes*. *Clothes* can work as *clothing* but *clothing* **can't** work as *clothes* because when you are talking about *clothing*, you are specifically looking at the clothing and **not who possesses it or what has been done to it by** **something/one else**. Since *clothes* are things that people wear, it can go both ways.

*Your* clothes

The wind picked up *the* clothes. . .

-In the second example, the clothes aren't mentioned as a possession, but a thing, just like clothing is used.

Comment: So which of the two sentences is correct?

Answer (score 0):

"The wind picked up the clothes wile it was drying on the line."

Correction: "The wind picked up the clothes while they were drying on the line." It's always a plural noun.